# Is it possible to seperate elements in actionbar?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-actionbar, toolbar

Is it possible to seperate elements in actionbar, like in the picture and how to do it?
Button on right side is from the menu of actionbar, where app:showAsAction="always"
I just need to make actionbar like this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Toolbar is just a ViewGroup . you can put your view inside it to make it look like this .

Comment: @adm can you give me any tips or code examples, pls

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this easily

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
        
    </LinearLayout>
    
    //other views


</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar_bg.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/purple_500"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

also change the theme of the application to no action bar from themes.xml

output

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my fault I didn't mention that button is from the menu of actionbar, where app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Can you make same thing, but for actionbar menu item, pls

Comment: @Diset I don't think it can, but you can put any button and use the Context Menu to display a menu